# Revert one change from the diff

Tags: git, diff, command-line-interface, dvcs, revert

Before committing, I see with `git diff` that I've made a change that I would rather not have made. Is there any way to revert this single change?

I suppose that I could use `git add -p` to commit the changes that I did intend to make, and then to checkout master. Is there a better way, preferably a way that does not require me to commit?

This is with Git 1.7.10.4 on Kubuntu Linux 12.10. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git reset --patch` (or `git reset -p`) does what you want.

The relevant bit of the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html):

> git reset (--patch | -p) [] [--] […]
>
> Interactively select hunks in the difference between the index and  (defaults to HEAD). The chosen hunks are applied in reverse to the index.
>
> This means that git reset -p is the opposite of git add -p, i.e. you can use it to selectively reset hunks. See the “Interactive Mode” section of git-add(1) to learn how to operate the --patch mode.

Note that `git reset` (applied on paths) does match `git add` — the latter stages files or chunks while the former unstages them, and so `git reset` supports the `--patch` option just like `git add` does.

You might also be interested to learn about `git checkout --patch` (or `git checkout -p`).

Answer (score 2):

`git checkout` also has `-p` option which is, basically, the same as `-p` in `git add`, but in reverse.

Just do:

```
git checkout -p <path>
```

(or without `path` if you want)

Like with `git add -p` you choose which changes to stage, here you choose which changes to revert.

Comment: Not quite that: `git checkout -p` updates files in the work tree, not touching the index.

Comment: @kostix Yeah, that's exactly what the OP was asking about.

Answer (score -1):

I have no silver bullet to submit, but when I have such a use case, I go with `git gui`. I just index all the changes I need then revert unwanted changes.

That's the same as a `git add -p`, but `git gui` makes the operation really neat.